# C# Comparing two lists (FileData)

Tags: c#, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I'm creating a program which is going through a folder structure. If something has changed, I want to write it into a list. My problem is that I don't know how to save the changes in the lstChanges when Comparing the two lists. What is the syntax for the if-statement? This is what I got for now:

```
public static void GoThroughFileSystem(DirectoryInfo x)
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in x.GetDirectories())
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Folder: {0}", d.Name);
            GoThroughFileSystem(d);
        }

        foreach (FileInfo f in x.GetFiles())
        {
            lstNew.Add(new FileData { path = f.FullName, ChangingDate = f.LastWriteTime });
            if (!lstOld.Contains(new FileData { path = f.FullName, ChangingDate = f.LastWriteTime }))
            {
                lstChanges.Add(new FileData { path = f.FullName, ChangingDate = f.LastWriteTime });
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The old list will never contain an object you are creating inline, you might want to check for properties instead of the whole object

Comment: How are you storing the "old" information in your old list? Is it a flat list or will it contains nested files?

Comment: @goaty im storing it by reading an xml-File. The lstNew will overwrite the xml when the application is executed.

Comment: I think you need to store this old data. So you can compare old and new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the `List<FileInfo>` of files from the last iteration in your `lstOld`, you can update your if statement to

```
//using System.Linq;

if (!lstOld.Any(old => old.Path == f.FullName && old.ChangingDate == f.LastWriteTime))
```

`List<>.Contains` uses default quality comparer. So, creating a `new FileInfo` will not work, unless `FileInfo` implements `IEquatable<T>.Equals()` properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try old fashion left outer join :)

```
var lParent = x.GetFiles();
var lChild = lstOld;

var differences = lParent.GroupJoin(
    lChild,
    p => p.FullName,
    c => c.LastWriteTime,
    (p, g) => g
        .Select(c => new { FullName = p.FullName, LastWriteTime = c.LastWriteTime})
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new { FullName = p.FullName, LastWriteTime = null}))
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

If your goal is to gather all unique values from both collections, the thing you need is called full outer join. For two identically typed collections you can just use union and remove common part:

```
lParent.Union(lChild).Except(lParent.Intersect(lChild));
```